# Can't boot Windows 8.1 after cloning from HDD to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, cloning

I have been running into this issue sometimes when cloning HDDs to new SSDs and was wondering is anyone had some ideas; I use [EaseUS backup](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm) normally to clone disks and any Windows 7 one will work fine, but sometimes with Windows 8 disks the SSD won't boot, giving me

The application or operating system couldn’t be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi

Error code: 0xc0000225

So I always try startup repair and sometimes that will fix it, other times I have to try a bunch of fixes from the web like fixing the bootrec and such, but I've had a couple disks that just will not boot no matter what, I even tried the Easy Recovery Essentials but can't get that to even boot if anyone has used it before. I'm mainly just looking for ideas because I think the issue is that the partitions on the original HDD usually have one primary one, and a few recovery ones, but on the cloned SSD all of the partitions are set as primary, and I can't figure out how to change that.

Comment: Try some different software, but we are not supposed to make recommendations here. AOMEI Backupper Standard is a free disk cloning program, I haven't used it but have used some of their other partition software with success.

Answer (score -1):

This means  EaseUS backup failed to modify the BCD (Boot Configuration Data) file for the new location during the restoration process. This file contains the key information for loading operating system. At the meantime, the information relates to the partition position parameters, so when you restore to a new location,  EaseUS backup need to modify it due to the new partition position.

To repair this problem, you may first use your Windows installation disc to perform a setup repair operation. Boot from your Windows installation disc and then choose Setup Repair Option, after that, follow the wizard to complete. If this solution doesn’t help, you can boot from your Windows Recovery Media and then choose Trouble Shoot -> Advanced Options -> Command Prompt

```
        CMD> bootrec /scanos
        CMD> bootrec /rebuildbcd
        CMD> bootrec /fixmbr
        CMD> bootrec /fixboot
```

Reboot. After that, your computer should back to normal.